# Формируется неверный относительный путь

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Вызываю метод `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(String)`, и получаю в адресной строке

> http://localhost:8080/pagename.jsp

в то время как должно быть

> http://localhost:8080/**AppName**/pagename.jsp.

Можно, конечно, передать в метод `AppName/pagename.jsp`, но во всех примерах, которые мне попадались в интернете, обходятся без названия приложения. С другой стороны, я понимаю, что `localhost:8080` не является верным адресом для приложения.

В связи с этим такой вопрос: существуют ли настройки, позволяющие не передавать название (которое можно и поменять) явно? Или где про это можно почитать/какие запросы вбивать в поисковик?

Comment: Что такое `jee` за метка? `java-ee` что ли?

Comment: угу, сейчас обозначают как jee

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри методы, которые даёт [HttpServlet**Request**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) для работы с адресом.
[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046620/5506820) довольно развернутый пример. При помощи конкатекции результатов вызовов данных методов можно получить вполне переносимый код.